# Comment traduire le « shutdown » : détails ?

Tags: vocabulaire, traduction, anglais, terminologie, politique

On a le « *(government) [shutdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Government_shutdowns_in_the_United_States)* » et l'article Wikipédia en français donne « [arrêt des activités gouvernementales](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arr%C3%AAt_des_activit%C3%A9s_gouvernementales_aux_%C3%89tats-Unis) ». Sur Franceterme on trouve « [suspension des services publics](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/result?francetermeSearchTerme=government%20shutdown&francetermeSearchDomaine=0&francetermeSearchSubmit=rechercher&action=search) » (et on nous dit de voir aussi le « [couperet budgétaire](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/terme/AFET144?from=list&francetermeSearchTerme=government%20shutdown&francetermeSearchDomaine=0) », le *fiscal cliff*, dont le sens [semble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_fiscal_cliff) ancré dans un moment précis de l'histoire.). Dans les médias de langue française on a souvent le terme de langue anglaise en italiques (*shutdown*) employé au masculin (le).

- Que doit-on privilégier pour décrire :

  - La situation américaine ?
  - Une situation similaire ailleurs ?
- Quel mot unique (à la manière de *shutdown*) et usuel convient le
  mieux pour présenter ou référer à ce genre de situation et surtout pourquoi ?

Comment: Pour des arrêt d'activité politique comme en Belgique ou en Irlande du Nord on va dire "arrêt des activités gouvernementales ou politique". Pour le service publique ce sera utilisé seulement si des services ou entreprises gouvernementales ne fonctionnent plus comme la poste, police... "coupure budgétaire" est seulement employé pour parler de changements économique d'un ministère ou autre fonction d’État.

Comment: @BaptisteGavalda Merci, votre propos est pas mal digne d'une réponse je crois...

Comment: si je trouve des sources pour appuyer mes propos je le posterais en réponse

Comment: je n'ai pas de réponse à apporter si ce n'est que j'ai toujours entendu le mot `shutdown` dans les vidéos françaises traitant du sujet. Ca sera sûrement compris, surtout à propos du shutdown américain

Comment: @BaptisteGavalda Oui, subsexdexter a raison. Je voudrais le voir comme réponse, s'il vous plaît. Personne a dèjâ posté vos propos, et je vous donnerais +1...

Answer (score 3):

Voici quelques citation sur des crises semblables ou assimilable pour montrer des exemples de vocabulaire utilisé.

"en panne de gouvernement" ; "est sans gouvernement"
[L’Irlande du Nord en panne de gouvernement depuis 541 jours](https://www.la-croix.com/Monde/Europe/LIrlande-Nord-panne-gouvernement-541-jours-2018-08-25-1200963857)

"541 jours de pilotage automatique" ; "le plus longtemps sans gouvernement"
[Une vie sans gouvernement, l’expérience belge](https://limprevu.fr/articles/28-04-2016/belgique-sans-gouvernement/)

"le blocage ne peut être évité" ; "le shutdown commencera à peser"
[Crise politique aux États-Unis : l'administration en shutdown](https://www.francetvinfo.fr/monde/usa/presidentielle/donald-trump/crise-politique-aux-etats-unis-l-administration-en-shutdown_2571737.html)

Mes propos non sourcé posté en commentaire:

Pour des arrêt d'activité politique comme en Belgique ou en Irlande du Nord on va dire "arrêt des activités gouvernementales ou politique". Pour le service publique ce sera utilisé seulement si des services ou entreprises gouvernementales ne fonctionnent plus comme la poste, police... "coupure budgétaire" est seulement employé pour parler de changements économique d'un ministère ou autre fonction d’État.

Answer (score 2):

Le mot « **shutdown** » est toujours utilisé tel quel en français probablement parce qu'il correspond à une situation unique qui n'a pas d'équivalent en dehors des États-Unis.

Il existe bien sûr des cas de blocage institutionnel ailleurs, mais aucun qui, en temps de paix, entraîne la suspension de la rémunération d'une partie importante des employés des services publics, et l'arrêt de ceux considérés comme non vitaux.

Les blocages survenus en Belgique ou en Irlande du Nord concernaient les décisions politiques mais n'ont pas affecté les services publics existants. Il y avait toujours une administration qui gèrait les affaires courantes et les fonctionnaires continuaient à être rémunérés.

À l'inverse, il peut arriver que certains fonctionnaires ne soient pas payés à cause de difficulté de trésorerie des états, par exemple au Gabon en 2018. On pourra alors évoquer, comme pour une entreprise, une cessation de paiement, banqueroute ou faillite.

Answer (score 0):

Je reprends simplement ce qu'on trouve sur [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arr%C3%AAt_des_activit%C3%A9s_gouvernementales_aux_%C3%89tats-Unis), en y ajoutant *fédéral* (voire *national* ; *central*, plus usuel pour moi avec *gouvernement*), pour plus de précision et afin d'indiquer que cela ne touche pas les gouvernements des États américains, et je complète avec les informations pertinentes entre parenthèses  :

> Arrêt des activités gouvernementales fédérales (ou nationales)
>   (*government shutdown*, ci-après *shutdown* ou « shutdown»).
>
> Arrêt des activités du gouvernement central...

Je me réfère aux autres réponses pour des contextes politiques autres que ceux des États-Unis. Par ailleurs dans des articles publiés après la question je trouve :

> [...] le président a reconnu, tout en le minimisant, l'impact de la
>   **fermeture** du gouvernement. ([La Presse](https://www.lapresse.ca/international/etats-unis/201901/13/01-5210870-shutdown-des-republicains-sopposent-a-une-declaration-durgence.php))
>
> Des responsables américains n'étaient pas disponibles pour commenter
>   le dossier en raison de la **paralysie** partielle du gouvernement
>   fédéral. ([La Presse](https://www.lapresse.ca/actualites/environnement/201901/13/01-5210862-arctique-le-canada-inquiet-des-projets-de-forage.php))

Ce termes (*fermeture, paralysie*) sont usuels mais demeurent (surtout le deuxième) assez vagues sans leur complément du nom. Le mot [fermeture](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fermeture) fait l'objet d'un emploi en contexte de décisions administratives, ce qui convient à mon avis.